# Windows 10, Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a text document with multiple lines like the one below:

```
20150202 14:25:31|20191014 23:00:00|20180104 11:19:46|20170412 09:52:17
```

I need to remove the time eg.: `14:25:31`

If I search using: `\.*\:.*\:.*\|" or "(\.*\:.*\:.*\|)`

It selects `:25:31|20191014 23:00:00|20180104 11:19:46|`

from the above example. Without the pipe it selects the entire line. I want to select just the time like `14:25:31` and `23:00:00` and `11:19:46` and `09:52:17` and remove them. The result should look like:

```
20150202|20191014|20180104|20170412
```

Please help me how I can search just the time and remove it one by one or all at once.

Answer (score 5):

Regular expression search + replace: Try replacing

> (\d+)\s+[\d\:]+

with

> \1

Just tried this:

> 20150202 14:25:31|20191014 23:00:00|20180104 11:19:46|20170412 09:52:17

goes to

> 20150202|20191014|20180104|20170412

Comment: Thank you so so much Anaksunaman and Bob. Both the answers/solutions work. Appreciate your quick response and help a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the answer already given, another way to approach this might be:

```
\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}
```

with a blank replacement (this should select only the time). With your example data and *Replace All*, the results match what you want:

20150202|20191014|20180104|20170412

[image: Regular Expression Screenshot]

Comment: Thank you so so much Anaksunaman and Bob. Both the answers/solutions work. Appreciate your quick response and help a lot.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad you got some solutions to help you. =)

Comment: Why are you using a dot `.` after `\d`? It should be `\d\d` or `\d{2}`

Comment: @Toto Unfortunately, just making poor assumptions about what comes between `\d` and `:`. Thank you for pointing that out. Corrected.

Comment: It's better but you could change the capture screen ;)

Comment: Lol whoops, yes I should. =)